# Make slack event message.im work only with bot mention

Tags: slack-api

I'm working on slack bot that will generate some creds for users, so it must be asked and reply in direct messages only.

It works with `message.im` Slack event, but event is triggered twice - when user asks bot AND when bot replies:
[image]

I have a trap for second event in my code:

```
    if "subtype" in SLACK_EVENT["event"]:
        print('Ignore bot event..')
        exit(0)
```

..but I'd like to get rid of that.

Can I somehow combine (add AND condition) `message.im` with `app_mention`?

So user will send IM to bot and only of bot was mentioned event will raise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. If you are only interested to a subset of message.im events you need to filter them out in your code as you suggested.